# How to get the select value?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that get seletedIndex==1 and make the div visible when selectedindex==1, what I want to do is to get the selectvalue not the index. Please teach me please. I'm new in javascript. if(document.frmregister.n_mode.selectedIndex==1) just like this to change selectedIndex==1 into selectvalue?

```
function BID_RFQ() {
    if (document.frmregister.n_mode.selectedIndex == 1) {
        document.getElementById("bidrfq").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("bidrfq").style.overflow = 'visible';
    } else if (document.frmregister.n_mode.selectedIndex == 2) {
        document.getElementById("bidrfq").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("bidrfq").style.overflow = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("bidrfq").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("bidrfq").style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: try `document.frmregister.n_mode.value`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this, I believe:

```
document.frmregister.n_mode.options[document.frmregister.n_mode.selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: Hi Shylo, i tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. document.frmregister.waa.options[document.frmregister.waa.selectedIndex].value==BIDDING

Comment: it's works ^_^ thanks, i just missed to edit some name elements :) thank you so much.

Comment: No Problem. Enjoy. It should open up a lot more interesting things you can do with your JS. Especially when you start using "onChange" events with the <SELECT>

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `value` of the selected option, you can get it with the `.value` property of the `select` element.

```
console.log(document.frmregister.n_mode.value);
```

---

This will automatically give you the `.value` of the selected `option` element, or if there's no `value` defined, it'll give you the `.text` of the `option`.

***demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/WdMTJ/

---

Note that as @RobG stated below, IE8 and lower will not return the `.text` if the `<option>` elements do not have `value` attributes. As such, you'll want to be certain that the values have been explicitly included.

Comment: @user2736012—your assertion is per the DOM spec, but in older versions of IE where option elements don't have a value attribute, the returned value is not the text.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, but that's in quite old versions, IE6 and maybe IE7 IIRC. I'm not terribly compelled to provide solutions for those browsers at this point.

Comment: @user2736012—it occurs in IE 8 also. The solution is to either always have a value attribute or property, or take a guess that if the value property is "" (empty string) then use the text property of the selected option. Likely there are devices based on IE that have the same issue.

Comment: @RobG: Hmm... I wasn't aware that IE8 was an issue. I'll update to note that `value` attributes will be required for broadest compatibility. I do still prefer this solution for its brevity and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
function BID_RFQ() {
    var n_mode = document.getElementById('n_mode');
    var bidrfq = document.getElementById('bidrfq');

    console.log(n_mode);
    /* Here's the important part. */
    var selectedOptionValue = n_mode.options[n_mode.selectedIndex].value;

    var visibility='visible',overflow='visible';

    if (selectedOptionValue  != 'One' && selectedOptionValue!='Two') {
      visibility=overflow='hidden';
    }

    bidrfq.style.visibility = visibility;
    bidrfq.style.overflow = overflow;

    return true;
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form id='frmregister'>
    <select id='n_mode' onchange='BID_RFQ()'>
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
      <option>Three</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    <div id="bidrfq">bidrfq</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An upvote or accepting an answer is usually the best way to thank somebody. :)